# Good read (blogs, books, articles) regards enterprise desktop application Design?

Tags: windows-os, enterprise, wpf

We are moving from web application to Window based Desktop application, for enterprise use.
ANy recommendation for reads around enterprise application design (Not web)?

Thanks,

Iris--

Comment: This question is not part of [What topics can I ask about?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The general principles of UX design, such as a user centered development process with user research, interaction design, prototyping etc., and the Windows  human interface guidelines (HIG) apply here. AFAIK the Windows HIG are in the web only and change over time.

This is the place for UX related questions. If you are interested in technical answers related to MS Windows development, then Stackoverflow or Software engineering might be better Stackexchange sites for you (though you should keep UX in mind  to convince your users of your product).